# Connected but no internet after installing connman

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, internet

On Arch Linux. Had `netctl` managing my connections, had internet access, switched to `connman` (installed `connman`, disabled `netctl` service).

Followed [instructions on the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ConnMan#Connecting_to_a_protected_access_point), connected to wifi network, provided password, `connman` reports connected. However, I still have no internet access.

```
$ ping google.com
[...] Temporary failure in name resolution

$ ping 8.8.8.8
[...] Destination Host Unreachable
[...] Destination Host Unreachable

$ connmanctl state
State = ready
OfflineMode = False
SessionMode = False

$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:54:a5:09:7e:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:d2:24:06:33:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.169.37/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global wlp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4ad2:24ff:fe06:330b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip route
default dev wlp2s0 scope link 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.169.37
```

Comment: `ip addr`? `ip route`?

Comment: @ajeh added to the question!

Comment: Can you ping your hotspot/router?

Comment: If by that you mean `ping 169.254.169.37` then yes! I'm a bit clueless about this, sorry.

Comment: That will be yourself, as `localhost`, but you need to make sure you can reach out to the WiFi device which you are hoping to use to connect to the rest of the Internet. You need to find out its IP address and try to ping that.

Comment: Took a while to understand what you wanted but I got there, learning. My router says it's ip is `192.168.1.1` and `ping -c4 192.168.1.1` gives 100% packet loss.

Comment: @GAD3R `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 70 May 23 20:03 /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: `command not found` but `find / -name connman_resolvconf.conf` gives no output.

Comment: `/var/run/connman` doesn't exist. Also tried with `find` and checking with `su`

Comment: You are on a network which is different from your router network. Your local IP has to be in the 192.168.1.* network.

Comment: @GAD3R made the symlink, restarted the service and dis/connected, still nothing.

Comment: @ajeh how do I fix that?